# List of Buddhist Forums

Tags: discussion, site-promotion

I think we need to mention the site in different forums. Any suggestion on particular forums and who would volunteer to do it?

Comment: This was already done earlier on, but it wouldn't hurt to do it again now that we're more mature as a site.

Comment: Considering the Buddhist population who might have access to the web the participation is too low. We need to get more people aware.

Answer (score 2):

> Considering the Buddhist population who might have access to the web the participation is too low. We need to get more people aware.

I fear that it might perhaps not be useful to 'spam' non-Buddhist forums with unsolicited mentions of this site.

I suspect that Google ranks this site quite highly for relevant searches. For example, on my machine, https://www.google.com/search?q=buddhist+monk+physical+exercise returns [Physical Exercise as a Monk?](https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/questions/3301/physical-exercise-as-a-monk) on its first page of search results.

Therefore I think it's possible that the best way to help is to put useful content on the site, which people will find if and when they look for it.

It would also be useful to consider what promotional methods are recommended by StackExchange, which has experience from several sites. See for example [Announcer, Booster, and Publicist Badges](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/09/announcer-booster-and-publicist-badges/): it suggests that you 'share' the links to the topics which you like, using your own Twitter, Google+ and/or Facebook account.